# MacTeX 2019 gives "! LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \not= already defined."

Tags: luatex, mactex, latex3

I have a document, that compiles fine on MacTeX 2017, which is installed on my desktop machine. I now installed MacTeX 2019 on my laptop and get this cryptic error:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.t
ex)

! LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \not= already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.3954 \NewNegationCommand { = }    { \neq   }

?
```

Does anyone understand what this is about?

---

Edit:

MWE:

```
\documentclass[usenames,dipsnames,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Gives:

```
$ latexmk -pdf -lualatex test.tex
[...]
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.t
ex)

! LaTeX3 Error: Control sequence \not= already defined.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              

l.3954 \NewNegationCommand { = }    { \neq   }

?
```

Comment: What's the purpose of loading `unicode-math` along with `newtxmath` and `ebgaramond-maths`?

Comment: huh? :) I don't know... Is this expected not to work?

Comment: Off-topic: Is `dipsnames` a typo? I have encountered `dvipsnames` before, but never `dipsnames`.

Comment: oops yea typo :)

Comment: You are loading three package for math fonts (`newtxmath`, `ebgaramond-maths`, `unicode-math`). Of course you can only use a single math font at a time.  Which one do you want to use?

Comment: @HenriMenke That's the thing, I want to use parts from all three of them :/ `$\hookrightarrow$` from `unicode-math`, `symbols` and `large symbols` as stated by @egreg below from `newtxmath` and then `operators` and `letters` from `ebgaramond-maths`... Or something like that. I don't quite understand this all...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The example fails also on my TeX Live (MacTeX) 2017, probably because of updates you didn't apply.

The problem is simple: you are using too many math font packages. Loading `newtxmath` before `ebgaramond-maths` is recommended, because the latter only acts on the `operators` and `letters` math groups, not on `symbols` and `largesymbols`.

If you load `unicode-math`, all these settings to math fonts will be completely discarded and you'd get Latin Modern Math.

If you add

```latex
\[
abc+\int f(x)\,dx
\]
```

to your test document and compile skipping past the errors, you get

[image]

Removing `\usepackage{unicode-math}` not only removes the errors, but produces

[image]

Comment: I have tested a bit more and it seems like `unicode-math` has a nice looking `$\hookrightarrow$` that I can use in MacTex 17 by loading that package before the other ones. So it seems like I still would like to "load too many font packages" but maybe I am missing something...

Comment: @jonalv Adding it before or after other font packages is irrelevant, because `unicode-math` does most of its work at begin document. You just remove those errors, getting a couple of different ones, but the document will use Latin Modern Math for math.

Comment: Yea so it seems, you are right as usual.  I guess I can't use that awesome looking `$\hookrightarrow$` together with EB Garamond then :(

Comment: @jonalv You can import the symbol from the legacy `stix` fonts.

Comment: For reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/499358/how-to-import-the-hookrightarrow-from-stix