# How to import the `\hookrightarrow` from STIX?

Tags: symbols, stix

In a comment on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/499227/298 @egreg said, that I could import the good looking `\hookrightarrow` from STIX. I found this [How to import the summation symbol from the "STIX" font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366566/how-to-import-the-summation-symbol-from-the-stix-font) and tried to apply it in my use case. I got this far:

```
\documentclass[usenames,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}


\makeatletter
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\makeatother

\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{xlargesymbols}{LS2}{stixex}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nicearrow}{\mathop}{RelationsSTIX}{U+21AA}

\lstset{ language=R, 
           basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
           frame=single,
           breaklines=true,
           postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\nicearrrow$}\space}, 
           showstringspaces=false
        }
\begin{document}
\noindent In this example I want to use the nice looking \texttt{\textbackslash hookrightarrow} from STIX fonts.
\begin{lstlisting}
> install.packages("devtools")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/devtools_1.6.1.tgz'
[...]
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/6s/skl7sm9511g6_cw844vldx540000gp/T//RtmpUbrziM/downloaded_packages
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

But I must admit, that I don't understand, what is going on with the `\DeclareMathSymbol{\sumop}{\mathop}{xlargesymbols}{"B3}` part nor how I should do it in my case. What is `"B3` and what is the name of the font I should use?

Please explain, how I can find this out as well, so it is easier when trying to do this for yet another symbol in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look into the `stix.sty` file for `\hookrightarrow`. You will find

```latex
\stix@MathSymbol{\hookrightarrow}           {\mathrel}{arrows1}{"B1}
```

Good, the symbol belongs to the `arrows1` math group. Let's look for it:

```latex
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows1}       {LS1}{stixsf}   {m} {n}
```

OK, we need the LS1 encoding; we find its first occurrence

```latex
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{\noaccents@}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix}{m}{n}
```

We don't need the parts pertaining to LS2. Change `\stix@MathSymbol` into `\DeclareMathSymbol` and you're done. You might want to change `arrows1` into another name.

```latex
\documentclass[usenames,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{arrows1}{LS1}{stixsf}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nicearrow}{\mathrel}{arrows1}{"B1}

\lstset{ language=R, 
           basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
           frame=single,
           breaklines=true,
           postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{$\nicearrow$}\space}, 
           showstringspaces=false
        }

\begin{document}

\noindent In this example I want to use the nice looking \texttt{\textbackslash hookrightarrow} from STIX fonts.
\begin{lstlisting}
> install.packages("devtools")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/devtools_1.6.1.tgz'
[...]
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/6s/skl7sm9511g6_cw844vldx540000gp/T//RtmpUbrziM/downloaded_packages
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you don't plan to use the arrow in math mode, but just for listings, you don't need to set up symbol fonts.

```latex
\documentclass[usenames,article,oneside]{memoir}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[lining]{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}

\newfontface{\stixsymbols}{STIX Two Math}
\newcommand{\nicearrow}{{\normalfont\stixsymbols\symbol{"21AA}}}

\lstset{ language=R, 
           basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily, 
           frame=single,
           breaklines=true,
           postbreak=\mbox{\textcolor{red}{\nicearrow}\space}, 
           showstringspaces=false
        }

\begin{document}

\noindent In this example I want to use the nice looking \texttt{\textbackslash hookrightarrow} from STIX fonts.
\begin{lstlisting}
> install.packages("devtools")
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/macosx/contrib/3.0/devtools_1.6.1.tgz'
[...]
The downloaded binary packages are in
    /var/folders/6s/skl7sm9511g6_cw844vldx540000gp/T//RtmpUbrziM/downloaded_packages
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```